# Splitting SES of modules: necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules

> Show that a short exact sequence of left R-modules $0 → A →^i B →^p C$
>   $→ 0$ is split if and only if there exists $q : B → A$ with $q\circ i =$
>   $1_A.$

There are some key theorems and lemmas I am missing. Could someone mercifully provide a hint for me?

Comment: What is your defintion of split?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SplitExactSequence.html

Comment: Given $q$, you have a map $q:B \to A$ and a map $p:B \to C$. Should be pretty easy to find the needed isomorphism $B\to A \oplus C$ then.

Comment: @MooS that's only one-way of the proof. And we don't know that q,p are invertible.

Comment: Of course $p,q$ are not invertible. That is nowhere required. It was just a hint how to get the isomorphism. Showing that it actually is an isomorphism is left to you.

Comment: I think I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define $\Psi: B\to A\oplus C$ such that $\Psi(b)=(q(b),p(b))$.
The map is injective because if $(q(b_1),p(b_1))= (q(b_2),p(b_2))$ than $b_1-b_2\in Ker(p)=Ran(i) $ and so there exists $a\in A$ such that $b_1-b_2=i(a) $ and so $q(b_1)-q(b_2)=0=qi (a)=a$ . Than $b_1=b_2$.
The map is surjective because for every $ (a,c)\in A\oplus C$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $p(b)=c $ and so $\Psi(b-i(q(b)-a))=(a,c)$